# What are the actual requirements for the "Copy Editor" badge as well as the "Strunk and White" badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

I looked up my edits, and I found out that I had 275 edits. However, the Strunk and White Badge says 80 posts edited will get the badge. Is there some kind of a catch, or did I misunderstood the badge? What about the Copy Editor's badge. Some guys had 800 edits, and they still don't have that badge. Why is this so?

Answer (score 3):

Let me see how giant a quote I can get away with...

[List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions):

> #### Strunk & White
>
> - silver; awarded once; same family as Copy Editor (gold)
> - Related to Editor (bronze)
> - Perform a total of 80 edits between questions and answers
>
>   - Edits on deleted posts do not count
>   - Edits to your own posts do not count
>   - Edits to CW posts **do** count
>   - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
>   - Tag wiki edits **do** count
>   - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges **do** count, once approved
> - Sources: [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges), [Tag wiki badge suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59329/tag-wiki-badge-suggestions), [How will Editor, Strunk & White and Copy Editor be affected by the new <2k edit mechanism?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76916/how-will-editor-strunk-white-and-copy-editor-be-affected-by-the-new-2k-edit-m)
>
> [...]
>
> #### Copy Editor
>
> - gold; awarded once; same family as Strunk & White (silver)
> - Related to Editor (bronze)
> - Perform a total of 500 edits between questions, answers and tag wikis
>
>   - Edits on deleted posts do not count
>   - Edits to your own posts do not count
>   - Edits to CW posts **do** count
>   - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
>   - Tag wiki edits **do** count
>   - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges **do** count, once approved
> - Sources: [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges), [Tag wiki badge suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59329/tag-wiki-badge-suggestions), [How will Editor, Strunk & White and Copy Editor be affected by the new <2k edit mechanism?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76916/how-will-editor-strunk-white-and-copy-editor-be-affected-by-the-new-2k-edit-m)

Comment: Whew! You got away with that!

Answer (score 1):

Both the badge descriptions make a reference to the number of edited posts, not the number of edits; this means that multiple edits for the same question (or answer) do not count.
I also think that only the edits made on the other users' posts are considered.